# monitoring bandwidth with ifHCOutOctets / ifHCInOctets

Tags: snmp

In reference to: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/8141-calculate-bandwidth-snmp.html

Looking at the input and output utilization. 
for instance if my number of seconds is 60

It says: Input utilization = ((ifInOctets * 8) * 100) / (60 * ifspeed)

What metric does it want for Ispeed? Megs? bytes? Gigs?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

The unit for ifSpeed is bits per second.  This is in the description of the ifSpeed OID, down at the bottom of the link you supplied.